# Click telegram link starts with tg in browser & Open it with telegram desktop

Tags: windows-10, browser, telegram-messenger

When I click on the link below in `FireFox` :

> tg://resolve?domain=BLABLABLA

I face this window:

[image]

When I click `Choose a different application`, I face this window:

[image]

`tdesktop.tg` has this error:

[image]

So I chose my telegram exe file manually.
But when I click Telegram.exe to open that link, the Telegram app opens but it doesn't show that link.

I also tried this registry way in Windows 10, But it seems it does not work on windows 10:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\tg\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\Jhon\\AppData\\Roaming\\Telegram Desktop\\+12\\Telegram.exe\" -workdir \"C:/Users/Jhon/AppData/Roaming/Telegram Desktop/+12/\" -- \"%1\""
```

Please guide me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and just have resolved it by uninstalling then installing the Telegram app again. Make sure to uninstall it firstly, not only running the setup again.
After installing, there will be a new option named `Telegram Desktop` in the `Choose a different application` window, so choose it, not `Telegram.exe`

[image: See Picture]